# Is it good practice to use the form attribute and put input elements outside form tag in HTML?

Tags: html, forms, input, include

I just noticed an interesting way of placing input elements outside of form tag today.

```
<html>
    <!-- the form element -->
    <form id="testform" method="post" action="index.asp">
        <label for="text1">Text: </label>
        <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <!--- element outside form tag -->
    <label for="text2">Additional Text: </label>
    <input type="text" id="text2" name="text2" form="testform" />

</html>
```

I am just wondering if it is common to practice to do this. Should this method be avoided?
Tried googling for similar discussions but i really don't know how to phrase this.

Comment: There is no harm to use like this. `form` tag is only created to specify which input belongs to, posting methods, etc...

Comment: I am wondering about the best practice/performance issues with this. The problem i can imagine as of yet is that this method of placing elements outside form tag seems to introduce UI flexibility, but added more work to DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not common practice. In most cases, it offers no benefits but has a drawback: some old browsers do not support the `form` attribute, so things just don’t work on them.

An `input` element outside a `form` element has always been permitted. Such an element just won’t participate in any form submission, if it has no `form` attribute. But it can be used with client-side scripting.

The `form` attribute associates, in supporting browsers, the element with a form just as if the element were inside the form. This can be useful in complicated cases where e.g. one row of a table should contain fields of a form, another row fields of another form, etc. You cannot wrap just one row inside a form, and here the attribute comes to rescue: you put a `form` element inside one cell of the row and refer to that element in fields in other cells with the `form` attribute.

Comment: According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-attribute) the form attribute is still not supported in IE _or_ Edge browsers.

Comment: If you want to see the form attribute in MS Edge please vote here: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/7327649-add-support-for-the-form-attribute

Comment: @Henders it is now in Edge!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can definitely do this as of HTML5, using the `form` attribute on inputs that are located *outside* the `form` element; just like you did.

For more details and examples, see [HTML `<input>` form Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_form.asp) at W3 Schools.

Comment: MDN documentation for `form`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-form

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with putting them there, and they will be available within the DOM if you are doing something with javascript, etc. but when you submit the form, the values of your fields will not be in the results submitted.

Comment: In other words when you submit that form to index.asp, there will be no POST[text2] available (sorry php guy, not sure how that looks in asp)

Comment: text2 is actually submitted together. with text1

Comment: I guess that's what I get for not reading carefully. Missed the form attribute.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can put input element outside the form but how would you decide how and where you 're  going to post values of these elements.